# Is Marsden's Calculus book no good?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, soft-question, book-recommendation

One of the advantages of using Marsden's Calculus book is the fact that you can find it, under a certain license, 100% free online. After downloading a few of its chapters, I saw some quality on the material. But that was before I dove deep into it.

[image]

Yesterday I was reading the chapter on **double integrals over general regions**, section 17.2. The integrals are very involved, which is expected. But then I noticed a few things.

On exercise 10, the boundaries for the integral involve two functions whose intersection you cannot calculate analytically. Below you will find an image of the exercise and the graph in geogebra.

[image]

[image]

Without the correct boundaries, it's impossible to break the integral and calculate it piece by piece (which, by the way, would be Avery time consuming thing to do).

Also, on exercise 11, something similar happens, and even the answer on the back of the book shows an incorrect function (instead of plotting $y^{2/3}$, the author plots $y^{1/3}$

[image]

[image]

[image]

It seems like these exercises were not checked before publishing the book.

What is your opinion on Marsden's Calculus books? Should I keep using it or move to something else?

Comment: Why do you need the intersections anyway? // Also I don't see any problem with the second question except for the mistake in the diagram, which doesn't invalidate the question itself.

Comment: I disagree. First of all, the intervals define whether you need to "break" the double integral into pieces. There is also the case for the second exercise: if you have wrong intervals, the answer won't be correct (if you actually draw the correct functions on the second exercise, you will notice that the intervals are much harder to find).

Comment: You don't need to break the interval into pieces. It seems you are trying to find the area between the curves, but that is not what $\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}$ means. There is no requirement for the upper limit to be greater than the lower limit; we have $\int_a^bf(y)\,dy=F(b)-F(a)$ even if $b<a$. So you can just close your eyes and calculate.

Comment: And come to think of it the graph for $x=y^{2/3}$ looks very similar to the graph for $x=y^{1/3}$, so I am no longer even convinced that the diagram has a mistake.

Comment: @Rahul the two graphs look nothing alike (as seen on the new post edit). Also, I'm pretty sure that if we do not take into consideration the order of the curves, reversing it will produce a wrong result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though I'm not familiar with this particular book, I think I do have something to say that will be helpful. Many math books have typographical errors in spite of having been proofread by dozens of intelligent people. Even if you have found a typo in this particular book, that doesn't mean it's a bad book.

Whenever you read any math book, you should always be on the lookout for typos. This is not just because a good book might still have some typos. It's because you should be trying to think deeply about what you read, and asking "Is it true? Does it make sense?"

Writing a good book on calculus is a long, time-consuming, difficult, and in some ways thankless jobs. It's quite remarkable that we live in an age when there are people who are not only willing to produce such a book, but also willing to make it available freely.

Comment: after reading your answer I realised that I may have come out somewhat passive aggressive, and that was absolutely not my intention. I do respect authors who spend a great amount of time on their lives to create what will be a building block of a student's education. I will, from now on, watch out for those typos - I can only imagine that, invariably, something written in paper will end up being transcribed in a wrong way. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @bru1987 No worries! You're learning complicated material, you're on the lookout for better ways of doing things, and you're taking time to ask for advice. These are all good things. Also, I think the fact that we can have discussions like these on Stack Exchange, is one of the things that makes Stack Exchange great!